# How to read a wider range of voltages into the SA ADC on a PSoC4?

Tags: adc, voltage-measurement, psoc

I want to read in a larger range of voltages into the SA ADC on the PSoC4, however as stated on the data sheet for the ADC component the different modes can only allow a range of 0 to 2 - 3 V and I would like to extend the range to about 10V, is this possible? and how to go about doing so.

**Edit** - Is it possible to perhaps sacrifice precision for a wider range? the ADC will give a value up to 3 decimal points.

[SA ADC datasheet](http://www.cypress.com/?docID=45835)

Comment: Same as always: attenuate the signal externally.

Comment: How do you suggest doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resistive divider in series with a (suitably wideband, as required by your application) op-amp configured as a voltage follower for impedance matching will do what you need, as long as your signal is entirely DC.  The resistor values in the following circuit will turn a 0-10V signal into a 0-2.04V signal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFqSw8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you actually mean "a 10V peak to peak AC signal" then the circuit will require some revision.

Yes, you will have to sacrifice precision.  A 12-bit ADC has 4096 quantization steps.  If you apply a 3V signal, each step covers ~0.73mV.  If you apply a 10V signal, each step covers ~2.44mV.